# PHP MySql search with LIKE matches too many rows

Tags: php, mysql, search, sql-like

I've taken over a site which uses a LIKE query to search in a field of delimited values. A typical field might look like this:

```
129|145|181
```

And the query looks like this:

```
SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members like '$arr[0]'
```

The problem is that when this searches for, e.g. "29", it returns fields with "129" in them. I want it to only return fields with "29" in them. Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks,
G

Comment: And this is the problem with storing delimited values in a field rather than normalizing your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members like '%|$arr[0]|%' OR members like '$arr[0]|%' OR members like '%|$arr[0]'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still returns 129 when searching for 29, I guess because '$arr[0]|%' matches both 129| and 29| ? Actually, no that shouldn't happen since there's not wildcard at the start of it... weird.

Comment: My fault -- the argument being passed already had %..% embedded in it. This works perfectly now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: exploding in php and quering in db will be expensive , i think we need to use IN query

Answer (score 5):

Use this , faster and efficient.

```
$str="129|145|181";
$newstr=str_replace("|",",",$str);
$sql='SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members IN('.$newstr.')'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id,title 
  FROM research 
 WHERE CONCAT('|',members,'|') like '|29|'
```

or

```
SELECT id,title  
  FROM research  
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(29,REPLACE('|',',',members))
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of 'patching' around with this method i'd recommend to use **JSON** to store numbers
and array-like stuff which always has **""** around value or key.

Comment: I'd recommend proper normalisation... JSON and serialized arrays are even harder to search than character-separated because both key and value are quoted

Answer (score 0):

You can do.

```
SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members ='$arr[0]'
```

For array of members you should  in operator.

```
SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members in (121,123)
```

If its a string then

```
memebers in ('121','123')
```

You need to do the formating.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a numbers is **contained** in this field, here is a complete answer :

```
SELECT id,title FROM research WHERE members like '%|$arr[0]' OR members like '$arr[0]|%' or members like '%|$arr[0]|%'
```